# Creating a 2D list of recursive patterns without slicing or list()

Tags: python

I need to write a function or a for-loop that receives or loop through a list of strings and returns this pattern:

> [['alpha'], ['alpha', 'beta'], ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'], ['alpha',
> 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']]

**I'm not allowed to use list slicing or list().**  The main purpose is to explore all the solutions with and without copy. Here is what I have tried but with list():

```
input = [['alpha',[]], ['beta',[]], ['gamma',[]], ['delta',[]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(input, columns=['Sequence','DNA'])
knn, dna_list=[],[]

for j, row in df.iterrows():
    knn.append(row['Sequence'])
    dna_list[j:] = [list(knn)]
```

Comment: What did you tried, what worked, what didn't ? We're not here to code for you but to help you fix your problems when you encounter one

Comment: @MariusROBERT I have revised the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack to finish with pretty accumulate ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xDgIhEET7/YrtgITY2Nj4JYQCT/RIgN1wS@HXc/FOQzcv8zLDH1mpXm/cxng1KpgkNiHKG6bC1ATDsvTSc5AIkCp3wTs6p0LmNSjrvLfo1CPKhHcoZdIz5l/nAXLaRJfA@hsuTGzx2DQGqMs5fjjzVf8F4Jaq6NMzY@w)):

```
from itertools import accumulate

input = [['alpha',[]], ['beta',[]], ['gamma',[]], ['delta',[]]]

[*map(list.pop, input)]
output = [*accumulate(input)]

print(output)
```

Another ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwDIbveYrcuknx4kUEn6QEqay6wpaGLjvs6etsxeWU///CF9l0THy5Si4lsqyKd3TO@ElGb6wjsujMM@gR3n6ejzSE6ccIIK3aDJE55K@J4JUyLhYfe4f1wQ1wn//FqW4WF6p9U5y9SOChq6wHkBxZu8b6Uj4)):

```
output = inner = []
for s, _ in input:
    inner = [*inner, s]
    output.append(inner)
```

Shorter version:

```
output = i = []
for s, _ in input:
    output += [i := [*i, s]]
```

Comment: This is still using list() method. Any idea how to do it without list() or slicing like: `dna_list[j:] = [knn[:i+1]]`

Comment: @R.Toward Ah, right, I forgot about that, I guess I only thought about it for the inner lists, which I think is the primary target for that rule. Removed now.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with a nested for loop

```
    input = [['alpha', []], ['beta', []], ['gamma', []], ['delta', []]]
    result = []
    for i in range(len(input)):
        result.append([input[j][0] for j in range(0,i+1)])
```